Efficiently generate pseudorandom floats Uniform in [0,1) using Python with a PRNG that's not the Mersenne Twister?
I've done a Monte Carlo simulation using Python3's random.random(), and I want to cross-check the result by using a different PRNG, but still with Python.  Can this be done?
Apparently(?) random.getrandbits(k) uses Wichmann-Hill instead of MersenneTwister, but this returns an integer with the specified number of bits. Can this be adapted somehow?
Also, I'm using the pypy interpreter because of an approximate 10x speed advantage (but it can't import numpy).

Possibly this one: https://pypi.org/project/mrg32k3a/. Mrg32k3a has excellent statistical properties.

@jpmarinier Thanks, I'll check it out.  I'm kind of habituated to Windows, but do sometimes venture into Linux.

Note that the Twister is used for everything in CPython's random, including by getrandbits().
You can get entirely different random numbers by using methods of the random.SystemRandom class instead. For example
>>> import random
>>> mygen = random.SystemRandom()
>>> mygen.random()
0.06723509434525832
>>> mygen.randrange(-20, 40)
23

This uses your platform's urandom() to get bits, which on most platforms is "cryptographically secure". It's slower, and cannot be "seeded" (results are not reproducible).

Thanks, I'll try it out.  There's also something in Python2's random module about "subclassing" to use Wichmann-Hill, but I'm unclear how to use it, in case I wanted to try that with Python2.

You can subclass Random to get a class that uses any basic generator you want. That's what SystemRandom does. But it's not trivial - you'll need to do work. Wichmann-Hill in particular can no longer be recommended for any serious use - it's too weak by modern standards. " It exhibits 12 clear failures in the TestU01 Crush suite and 22 in the BigCrush suite (L'Ecuyer, 2007)."
